# Automagically synonymise a non-existent, unhyphenated tag if the hyphenated version is created

Tags: feature-request, support, retag-request, synonym-request

As of this post, there are [474 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65617/possible-duplicate-tags-based-on) that are identical except for a hyphen. The 26 most dodgy are below.

It makes sense, to me at least, if once a tag has been created the un-hyphenated should be automagically synonymised if it doesn't already exist? For instance if [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder) is created and [flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder) doesn't exist then [flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder) should be created and turned into a synonym of [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder).

---

Top 26 affected tags; is there any chance of getting these, and the others fixed?

<sup>Is the retagging process manual? If so, I won't blame anyone for ignoring this part!</sup>

[flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder)  204   --> [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder)  1353
[contextmenu](/questions/tagged/contextmenu)  1138  --> [context-menu](/questions/tagged/context-menu)  70
[codefirst](/questions/tagged/codefirst)  68    --> [code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first)  587
[autoincrement](/questions/tagged/autoincrement)  160   --> [auto-increment](/questions/tagged/auto-increment)  443
[codebehind](/questions/tagged/codebehind)  479   --> [code-behind](/questions/tagged/code-behind)  117
[onetomany](/questions/tagged/onetomany)  70    --> [one-to-many](/questions/tagged/one-to-many)  519
[serverside](/questions/tagged/serverside)  106   --> [server-side](/questions/tagged/server-side)  480
[fontsize](/questions/tagged/fontsize)  300   --> [font-size](/questions/tagged/font-size)  207
[multitouch](/questions/tagged/multitouch)  362   --> [multi-touch](/questions/tagged/multi-touch)  106
[readonly](/questions/tagged/readonly)  391   --> [read-only](/questions/tagged/read-only)  76
[modelbinding](/questions/tagged/modelbinding)  65    --> [model-binding](/questions/tagged/model-binding)  367
[isolatedstorage](/questions/tagged/isolatedstorage)  306   --> [isolated-storage](/questions/tagged/isolated-storage)  66
[dateformat](/questions/tagged/dateformat)  297   --> [date-format](/questions/tagged/date-format)  55
[htmlentities](/questions/tagged/htmlentities)  100   --> [html-entities](/questions/tagged/html-entities)  233
[keyvalue](/questions/tagged/keyvalue)  65    --> [key-value](/questions/tagged/key-value)  221
[autoupdate](/questions/tagged/autoupdate)  57    --> [auto-update](/questions/tagged/auto-update)  219
[adhoc](/questions/tagged/adhoc)  195   --> [ad-hoc](/questions/tagged/ad-hoc)  65
[textfile](/questions/tagged/textfile)  204   --> [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file)  55
[pageload](/questions/tagged/pageload)  160   --> [page-load](/questions/tagged/page-load)  93
[tablerow](/questions/tagged/tablerow)  153   --> [table-row](/questions/tagged/table-row)  64
[dataaccess](/questions/tagged/dataaccess)  53    --> [data-access](/questions/tagged/data-access)  135
[htmlencode](/questions/tagged/htmlencode)  58    --> [html-encode](/questions/tagged/html-encode)  114
[customview](/questions/tagged/customview)  54    --> [custom-view](/questions/tagged/custom-view)  116
[firstresponder](/questions/tagged/firstresponder)  56    --> [first-responder](/questions/tagged/first-responder)  81
[httpserver](/questions/tagged/httpserver)  58    --> [http-server](/questions/tagged/http-server)  66
[hpux](/questions/tagged/hpux)  56    --> [hp-ux](/questions/tagged/hp-ux)  54

Comment: I'd say go with the multiples system already in place. If the tag minus hyphens matches any other tag minus hyphens, it already exists and the tag creation should fail. Creating automatic synonyms seems like a waste.

Comment: How do we know that the tag without a hyphen is the correct one? [Please change tag iphone4s to iphone-4s](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128865/please-change-tag-iphone4s-to-iphone-4s)

Comment: @animuson, ah. I didn't know that that was the case; couldn't find the correct wording obviously. Bo, I'm suggesting that the tag _with_ the hyphen is the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's already a feature in place to prevent such tags from appearing: you cannot create a tag that differs from an existing tag by only the presence or position of hyphens. (Moderators can work around this.) What you see are existing tags dating back from before this restriction was in place.

I agree with all your proposed tag synonyms. Note that some are synonyms already. Before the left-hand tags are merged into the right-hand tags, some tag wikis need copying over.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about anything being in place. It makes sense to clean up the remaining stuff though when something like this is done?