# The tag hyphenization filter has stopped working

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17479066/revisions), a user created [java8](/questions/tagged/java8) despite [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) existing.  I've left it alone for now.

[The system shouldn't permit this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128883/135887).

Is the [possible brokenness in the pluralization filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187406/135887) also related?

Comment: I was just able to create [tag:superping] despite [tag:super-ping] existing.  I'll edit this back into the question once the grace period ends as to provide proof.

Comment: As you can see, dashes are on sale today.

Comment: As super-ping was bugging me, I've found some alternate hyphens to abuse.  (Do you have *any* idea how hard it is for *me* to create three new tags for one question!?)

Comment: +1 for the tags on this question

Comment: looking into it...

Comment: is Brokenness a word?  If it is it probably shouldn't have two nn's - maybe I should ask on english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix rolled out in build 2013.7.9.826. The issues were indeed related. The checks were performed only on tags with approved synonyms. Only normal users with rep > 500 who are not mods will notice the change.